# Match two variables across days and check a third

Tags: python

I am checking data in a database that is being updated daily, I need to set up some controls to check whether these updates are done correctly.

I have 3 columns where 2 of them are identifiers (id and comp), the code should match these two across the two days, day t and day t-1. Then it should check for sign (-/+) changes in the val column.

If the sign is changed the code should output the sec-id.

```
   Day t-1                Day t
 id   comp   val     id     comp    val
KL102  bal  -0.12    KL102   bal    0.15
KL102  pol   0.55    KL102   pol   -0.48
2588   bal  -0.58    2588    bal   -0.88
2588   typ   1.8     2588    typ   -1.2
```

the question is, how can this be done? simply pointing me in the right direction, i am currently looking at different matching tutorials and other similar questions across the internet. So far i havent come across anything like, match two variables across dates and check a third.

Might it be easier if i split up the data, so i have one dataframe for each date? and do something like `if df1['id'] == df2['id'] & df1['comp'] == df2['comp']:` ?

Comment: I also have a date variable. I will never have more than the two dates i want to check.

Comment: What is the question and what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Mattias, sorry for being unclear, the question is, how can this be done? simply pointing me in the right direction, i am currently looking at different matching tutorials and other similar questions across the internet. So far i havent come across anything like, match two variables across dates and check a third.

Comment: Might it be easier if i split up the data, so i have one dataframe for each date? and do something like if `df1['id'] == df2['id'] & df1['comp'] == df2['comp']:` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just add the new day as a new column by concatenating the data frames. (this step is not needed if you can just add the new date as a new column, then just proceed to the next step)

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['id1', 'id2'])
```

and then compare the two days to see if there has been any change.
The comparison can be done with numpys sign:

```
df['comp'] = np.sign(df['day 1']) + np.sign(df['day 2'])
df['output'] = df['day 1']
df['output'].loc[df['comp'] == 0] = df['day 2']
```

Comment: Hi Mattias, thanks for the answer. But how does this code take into account that it should match on both comp and id? as neither is unique in isolation, but the matching of the two are unique, so no more than one time does a row have the same comp and id.

Comment: Sorry, my first code snippet was rushed, this new one merges based on the two identifiers.